# Need to compare two dataframes of different length and update a column of one of the dataframe based on matching criteria in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes df1 and df2. 
df1 > df2 in size.

```
df1 -> A      B        C       D     E  F
       1   4-23-2015   abc    dcv    0  0
       2   5-23-2015   abc    dcvm    1  0
       3   4-24-2015   ab    dcv      0  0
       4   4-23-2014   abc    dcv     0  0

df2 -> A      B         C      D     E F
       1   4-23-2015   abc    dcv    0  0
       3   4-24-2015   abc    dcv    0  0
       9   4-23-2015   abc    dcv    0  0
```

Now I want to compare

```
df1$A with df2$A and df1$B with df2$B and when it is true then put df1$F =1. So my output for the above example will be

  df1 -> A      B        C       D     E  F
       1   4-23-2015   abc    dcv    0    1
       2   5-23-2015   abc    dcvm    1   0
       3   4-24-2015   ab    dcv      0   1
       4   4-23-2014   abc    dcv     0   0
```

The column B is a Date type column and also the comparison is done row vs row.

Comment: please show some example input or elaborate - are you comparing the data by index (row2 vs row2) and what to do with the non comparables (more records on df1 rights?)

Comment: yes...row vs row.....Nothing to do with the non comparable....

Comment: You could just do `merge(df1, df2, by = c("A", "B"), all.x = TRUE)` to see which rows were matched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is almost a usual `merge` dupe, but for both cleaner output and faster performance, I would suggest `data.table` binary left join with simultanious updating by reference. Something like

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df2, F := 1L, on = c("A", "B")]
df1
#    A         B   C    D E F
# 1: 1 4-23-2015 abc  dcv 0 1
# 2: 2 5-23-2015 abc dcvm 1 0
# 3: 3 4-24-2015  ab  dcv 0 1
# 4: 4 4-23-2014 abc  dcv 0 0
```

Otherwise, a simple `merge(df1, df2, by = c("A", "B"), all.x = TRUE)` will show you which rows were matched, but you will need to remove unnecessary columns and update `F` accordingly.

Comment: @tanay see [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) for some tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example,

```
df1$F[apply(df1[,c('A', 'B')], 1, paste, collapse = '') %in% apply(df2[,c('A', 'B')], 1, paste, collapse = '')] <- 1
df1
#  A         B   C    D E F
#1 1 4-23-2015 abc  dcv 0 1
#2 2 5-23-2015 abc dcvm 1 0
#3 3 4-24-2015  ab  dcv 0 1
#4 4 4-23-2014 abc  dcv 0 0
```